# What should be displayed on the x-axis of a funnel plot for a meta-analysis model that does not contain any moderators?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, metafor

I have performed a meta-analysis with the follwing attributes:

```
meta_escalc <- escalc(measure = "MN", mi = mean , sdi = SD, ni = ni, data=data )
```

However, I am not sure which diagnostic plot makes more sense.

This funnel plot displays the actual values (rather than residuals) on the x-axis, for a model without moderators.

```
res.1 <- rma(yi = yi, vi = vi, data = meta_escalc)
funnel(res.1)
```

[image: funnel plot for the model without moderators, with int.only = TRUE]

When displaying the funnel plot for the model with moderators the x-axis displays the residual values.

```
res.2 <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ mods, data=meta_escalc)
funnel(res.2)
```

[image: funnel plot when subgroups are defined as moderators]

When the model does not have any moderators, but we force it to display residuals on the x-axis by setting int.only = FALSE:

```
res.1$int.only <- FALSE
funnel(res.1)
```

[image: funnel plot when the model has no moderators, but is forced to display residuals on the x-axis]

Could you please explain which one is more suitable? and why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has already asked it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988493/create-funnel-plot-with-residuals-using-metafor and received the correct answer there.